# How to convert a variable into string in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I'm storing a command's output in a variable but when I use that variable's value for a string comparison it fails. So I want to make sure I convert the variable value in a string before doing the comparison.

```
user=`yarn application -list -appStates ALL -appTypes MAPREDUCE | grep application_id | awk -F "\t" '{print $4}'`
```

This populates a value in user, which when used in string comparison doesn't work as expected.

For ex: below command returns value for user as abc

```
user=`yarn application -list -appStates ALL -appTypes MAPREDUCE | grep application_id | awk -F "\t" '{print $4}'`

echo $user
abc
```

Now if I user user variable for comparison and take further action it fails.

```
if [[ "$user" != "def" ]] && [[ "$user" != "xyz" ]] && [[ "$user" != "abc" ]];then echo value not present; fi

value not present
```

As you can see it still prints "value not present" while $user is actually holding abc is value. I'm assuming it is because value stored in $user isn't really a string.

Question: How do I convert value in $user to a variable so that string comparison work or what other alternative I can implement to avoid the problem scenario.

I need to achieve this in bash.

Comment: Do `printf "%s" "$user" | cat -v` or `printf "%s" "$user" | hexdump -C` and inspect for unreadable characters. Note that using backticks is highly discouraged. Use `$(..)` for command substitution.

Comment: I agree with @KamilCuk: you probably have some whitespace at the end of your string.

Comment: thanks , it returns with below. Looks like there a space or some empty character in the beginning :
    printf "%s" "$user" | cat -v
  abc

Comment: Quite often, a simple `echo "[$user]"` will reveal problems.  If you see the close bracket `]` at the start of the line, you have CRLF (DOS-style) line endings in the string; if you see blanks or line breaks, that's a different problem.  If none of those show up, then it is time to do a hex dump (e.g. `echo "$user" | xxd -g 1`).  Sometimes, `user=$(echo $user)` — without double quotes on purpose — will solve it.  But getting a detailed picture of what's actually in the variable by using `"$user"` (inside double quotes) is crucial to resolving the problem.

Comment: Bash's basic type is string. You would have to explicitly declare any of the other types (e.g. array, int). (BTW these aren't types per se but I'm glossing over the details.)

Comment: Please post the output of `printf '%s' "$user" | xxd -g1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
user=yarn application -list -appStates ALL -appTypes MAPREDUCE | grep application_id | awk -F "\t" '{print $4}'
```

does not do what you think it does. It sets user to the value "yarn" then runs the rest of the line. Instead I think you want to do this:

```
user=$(yarn application -list -appStates ALL -appTypes MAPREDUCE | grep application_id | awk -F "\t" '{print $4}')
```

Using the `$(..)` syntax will run the command and store its output in the user variable.

Comment: sorry thats a formatting issue, the command is under backticks (``), so it does return an output like I showed as "abc"

Comment: The question has been fixed